# reshape the data by adding 2 columns with

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, tidyr, reshape2

I have a file with some codes and I want to add 2 columns which has fixed set of values in it. and I want to put: for each code in the file, put 2 columns with fixed set of values in it.

Using Reshape or tidyr or dplyr in R.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpmIz.jpg)
For example:
some_codes.csv has:
"
  codes
  123
  234
  [r](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnsye.jpg)345
"

> and i want to create 2 columns in this (set and category) which has fixed values.

codes  set category
123     1     a
123     2     b
123     3     c
234     1     a
234     2     b
234     3     c
345     1     a
345     2     b
345     3     c

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.

For each code, you cbind the value and the dataframe. `purrr::map_dfr` will then join everything together as a dataframe by binding rows.

```
library(tidyverse)
codes = data.frame(codes=c(123,234,345))
categ = data.frame(set=1:3, categ=c("a","b","c"))
codes$codes %>% map_dfr(~{cbind(code=.x,categ)})
```

But as Tung said, you should post a reproducible example next time. You can use the `dput` function for this.